# why Or condition not working unix shell scipt

Tags: shell, sh, ksh

am checking argument length equals to 5 or six and tried like below,

```
 argc=$#
 if [ $argc  -ne 5 -o $argc -ne 6 ]; then
  echo "yes"
 fi

 if [ $# -ne 5 -o $# -ne 6 ]; then
 echo
 fi

 if [ $argc != 5 ] || [ $argc != 6 ]; then
 echo
 fi
```

in all cases its not meeting the condition could you please correct me where am doing wrong?

Comment: What is the value of `$#`?

Comment: it returns command line argument length.

Answer (score 2):

Your condition is saying: if `argc` is not equal to `5` or if `argc` is not equal to `6` echo `yes`. This will always be met, so `yes` will always print out. You want `if [ $argc -ne 5 -a $argc -ne 6 ]` or `if [ $# -ne 5 -a $# -ne 6 ]`, etc.

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: If your positive condition is `x = A || x = B` then its negative is `x ≠ A && x ≠ B`

Comment: it will check the commnad line parameter length.. the lengh should equls to 5 or the lengh should equls to 6.. if lengh not equals to 5 or 6, say 4 or 7.. it should go inside if block.

Comment: For that you want `if [ $argc -ne 5 -a $argc -ne 6 ]` like I said.

Comment: Don't use `-a`; use `[ $# -ne 5 ] && [ $# -ne 6 ]`.

Answer (score 0):

In plain English your condition reads "(number of arguments not equals 5) OR (number of arguments not equals 6)". This condition is always true, as number arguments can not simultaneously be 5 and 6. May be you wanted to use AND instead?

```
if [ $# -ne 5 -a $# -ne 6 ]; then
    echo "yes"
fi
```

Comment: yes i agree.. still i dont undersand why the -o not worked.

Comment: Well the `-o` condition worked actually. When you join two logical expressions using OR operator, the entire expression evaluates to true if any one of the expression is true. Only way the combined expression can evaluate to FALSE is if both the expressions (combined by OR) are false.
In this particular example you have OR-ed two expressions which can never be false at same time, hence your if condition will always evaluate to TRUE.